# Paypal: We're sorry, something when wrong while fetching test accounts. Please try again

Tags: paypal

I can´t believe what happen with paypal, I have lost a lot time trying to change the IPN url from one sandbox account, but I can´t because when I try to login on the sandbox website of paypla, I can´t...

Ok, I login on paypal developers, to consult my sandbox accounts, and I get this:

[image]

I had 5 sandbox accounts, on to simulate my company. I get nothing now.

Someone can help me? I don´t think this can be a normal error of paypal...

Comment: This seem to happen very often lately, it's very annoying. Unfortunately, it looks to be an issue on the PayPal's side, the only thing we can do is just wait.

Comment: Update: The problem appears now  to be fixed. If you continue to have issues, try deleting all the cookies associated with the paypal.com domain and subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

there was issues with sandbox; please review this Link for future updates. See Answer below.

https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search

Sandbox Status Update
Notification: We are experiencing a system issue which may be affecting login to some accounts on the PayPal Sandbox. Please see the details below.

Developers testing in the PayPal Sandbox may encounter a blank page when accessing the Merchant Manager accounts via https://paypalmanager.sandbox.paypal.com/

Our technical teams are actively working towards resolving these issues. We will provide an update as soon as the issue is resolved.
Sent Nov 6, 2015 05:20 PM MST by ASH

Comment: I haven't been able to login to the sandbox for weeks. I don't understand what's going on at a major company like PayPal...

Comment: Hey Devin, when you say 'sandbox' are you saying logging into sandbox.paypal.com  or developer.paypal.com? Just checking as I understand that multiple paypal login instances causes login failures with sandbox.paypal.com. You should be able to get in as I have a few accounts without failure. Let me know so I can give some direction to help you.